# Login issue on onepage checkout on Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout, login

I have an issue on my Magento 1.8.1 in the **onepage checkout during the customer login**. Instead to keep on checkout page he is redirect to login form without to be logged and when ask to insert the credential and click login is redirect on customer dashboard.

I checked all missed formkey in all files need to add this code but I didn't find where it is missed.

More over I followed this solution: [Onepage checkout: Already registered customer login redirects to create an account or login page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/onepage-checkout-already-registered-customer-login-redirects-to-create-an-accou) but without success

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check the admin settings by which you can manage customer redirection after login post send.

For that, please go to `admin > System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Loggin Option`, then make **Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** make it **NO**